# Is it possible to code an app for self use only?

Tags: ios

I'm wondering. If i have an idea for an app, which will just benefit myself, is there a way for me (without entering any Apple developer program) to code an iOS app and then save it on my device or take the source code of my program and use some kind of software on it to be able to "install it"/put it on my iPhone for personal use? That would have been great.

Let's say that this is not possible (which is most likely) how do you make a user-testing-study on your app before releasing it to the App Store? Is this only possible if one have entered a developer program?

Comment: you need to enter developer program to deploy app to device. or you can jailbreak it and do whatever you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation onto your device requires a code signing certificate which requires a developer program subscription.

One *could* jailbreak a device to get around this, but that comes with its own set of problems.

**UPDATE**

Apple has announced at WWDC 2015 that starting with Xcode 7 only an Apple ID is required to run your own code on your development device.

Comment: Thank you, this answers all of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  You can run it on the simulator, but not on a device.

You can do paper prototyping, or you can do testing on the simulator.